# When methods of managed bean should be synchronized?

Tags: jsf, thread-safety, managed-bean

Do we have to synchronize a managed bean method if this method is called by e.g. `commandButton` component as a AJAX request, and the method is operating on a instance variable of managed bean?

Let's say we have this simple managed bean :

```
public class ManagedBeanTest {

  private int count;

  public int getCount() {
    return count;
  }

  public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
  }

  public String increaseCount() {
    count++;
    return null;
  }

}
```

So if in this case the `increaseCount` method is called by a `commandButton` component inside `action`, do I have to synchronize this method?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Just to clarify for other people reading about this subject:

If we access a method which uses only local variables (not instance variables), it will not be necessary to synchronize anything because each thread accessing the method will have a different copy of these variables (which will be destroyed when the method ends its execution).

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *When methods of managed bean should be synchronized?*

When the managed bean is put in the wrong scope. In properly designed apps that is, thus, never.

In **your particular** example, you should be using [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of `int` and possibly a bunch of `synchronized` modifiers.

```
private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

public int getCount() {
    return count.get();
}

public void incrementCount() {
    count.incrementAndGet();
}

// No setter!
```

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)
- [Are JSF 2.x @ViewScoped managed beans thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410723/are-jsf-2-x-viewscoped-beans-thread-safe/7410894#7410894)

Answer (score 2):

It depends of use case and scope of bean. If your managed bean is request scoped there is no need for any synchronization. In view scoped beans, there is no possibility of race conditioning problems when you have multiple AJAX requests (as per JSF 2 specification and chapter about Ajax Request Queueing AJAX requests from same client are queued and executed in sequence). You should however synchronize session scoped bean methods (if, for example, user open page in multiple tabs). And of course methods of applications scoped beans, which manipulates on fields of managed bean should be synchronized.

Comment: According to the JSF specification AJAX requests must be queued on the client, so the probability of concurrent access is zero.

Comment: @skuntsel thank you, I overlook that part of specification. I edited answer.